# Mongodb 4.2 uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: command createUser requires authentication

Tags: mongodb

```
db.createUser(
...    {
...        user: "jhyunetp1",
...        pwd: passwordPrompt(),
...        roles:["root"]
...    });
```

> Enter password:
>   2020-03-09T08:53:58.284+0000 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: command createUser requires authentication :

It drives me crazy.

```
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
port = 27017

# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling
journal=true

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu = true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true
auth = true
```

My conf.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You need to run it without auth, create the "user admin" and that will let you create further users. And then turn the auth back on.

Comment: @Yahya thank you for your answer. I did turn it off and on. I guess I edited another file by mistake.
I don't know what this file is for. 
I found the correct file and followed your advice. Thank you.
BTW, Do you know why we need to turn 'authentication' off when 'command createUser requires authentication :' message pops up?
This is strange because it requires authentication.

Comment: Because if you start MongoDB with authentication, there's no turning back. So the advice is to first crate the user admin, then turn it on. If you forget to do it, you can still follow the same procedure.

Comment: I guess my message was mis-delivered, I mean
command createUser requires authentication But what we need to do is not to turn 'auth' on in order to createUser.
Doesn't it look strange for you?

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of everyone else who ends up on this question. You need to start the mongod process without authentication (change that in config file). Login as local exception, which means you can connect to it via localhost. Create a user who has user admin privileges, so they can create further users. And then turn the authentication back on (restart the process, ofcourse).